# $wpdb in new OOP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to write my first Wordpress plugin. I'm using classes to make it easier to maintain.

I'm wondering how I can use the WPDB class in my wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb` is a `global` variable, which is an instantiation of the class already set up to talk to the `WordPress` database.

you can use it in this manner -

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."plg_table" );
echo $result;
```

For more info you can also check this link - [Link To CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

If its your first i prefer to modify the existing one that i suggested few days back, check this link as it may help you [showing plugin in frontend of website or in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816046/showing-plugin-in-frontend-of-website-or-in-page/10816329#10816329)